# Possible to have WCF STS with username/password and client certificate?

Tags: wcf, authentication, certificate, wif

I'm using WIF with STS. Everything works fine and the client authenticates by sending the username/password in the credentials.

We install clients at customer's sites.
What I would like is for each customer to use its own certificate for its clients. The reason for that is that there's no "customer-site" validation possible. I can deactivate some user accounts but I cannot disable all clients installed at a customer at once.
If each customer had a different certificate I could revoke the certificate and no client from that customer would be able to connect anymore.

I couldn't find any way to force the client to set its certificate to the communication. Usually this is automatic when the authentication mode is set to *certificate* but I need to set it to *windows* to be able to send the authentication.

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve that? Or let me know if that's just not possible.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure is, you just need to do a little footwork to get this going starting with a custom security binding extension element to describe the tokens and which one should be used for signing/endorsing. For purposes of explanation I will assume you *always* want both the certificate and a username/password passed.

In the custom binding element, you will need to create a [`TransportSecurityBindingElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.transportsecuritybindingelement.aspx) and add token parameters to it. There's three collections to add token parameters to: `SignedEncrypted`, `Signed` and `Endorsing`. For the scenario we're talking about here, I recommend adding the [`UserNameSecurityTokenParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.tokens.usernamesecuritytokenparameters.aspx) to the `SignedEncrypted` collection and the [`X509SSecurityTokenParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.tokens.x509securitytokenparameters.aspx) to the `Endorsing` collection. This means that the message validity/integrity is provided by the certificate token rather than the username/password and the username/password token will be signed *and* encrypted by the certificate token. This will look something like the following:

```
public class MySecurityBindingElement : BindingElementExtensionElement
{
    public override void ApplyConfiguration(BindingElement bindingElement)
    {
        base.ApplyConfiguration(bindingElement);

        TransportSecurityBindingElement transportSecurityBindingElement = (TransportSecurityBindingElement)bindingElement;

        transportSecurityBindingElement.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.SignedEncrypted.Add(new UserNameSecurityTokenParameters());

        transportSecurityBindingElement.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Endorsing.Add(new X509SecurityTokenParameters
        {
            InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient,
            ReferenceStyle = SecurityTokenReferenceStyle.Internal,
            RequireDerivedKeys = false,
            X509ReferenceStyle = X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.Any
        });         
    }

    protected override BindingElement CreateBindingElement()
    {
        TransportSecurityBindingElement result = new TransportSecurityBindingElement
        {
            IncludeTimestamp = true,
            LocalClientSettings.DetectReplays = false,
            LocalServiceSettings.DetectReplays = false
        };

        this.ApplyConfiguration(result);

        return result;
     }
}
```

Then, from a client perspective, you just make sure to set both the certificate and username password get set for each channel you're using to communicate with the server. You can do this at runtime by setting the properties on [the `Credentials` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channelfactory.credentials.aspx) of either the `ChannelFactory` or a standard WCF, [`ClientBase` proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms553830.aspx) class. Another thing you can do is set the client certificate via an endpoint behavior like so:

```
<endpointBehavior>
    <behavior name="MyBehavior">
        <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="MySubject" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
        </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
</endpointBehavior>
```

Done this way, you will only ever need to explicitly set the username/password at runtime.

Finally, at the STS, you can read the tokens that are specified by the user via the [`OperationContext::SupportingTokens`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.supportingtokens.aspx) property. You'll find instances of [`UserNameSecurityToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.usernamesecuritytoken.aspx) and [`X509SecurityToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.x509securitytoken.aspx) in the collection and from there you can use those to authenticate the caller.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I didn't think of using a custom security binding. I'll try it out tomorrow then. I was hoping there was a "built-in" way of doing it though.

Comment: Nothing out of the box, but at least the knobs and switches are there. ;)

Comment: So this applies to a custom STS or can this be done via ADFS v2.0?

Comment: The "Token Issuance" portion of ADFS 2.0 is an STS implementation. That said, this really doesn't have anything to do with an sending tokens to an STS specific. You can send multiple security tokens along with any request using the same binding.